# Mongodb aggregate show count with zero value on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have tried to apply aggregation on multiple fields to show count but it does not works.

I have 4 to 5 different values lets say value1,value2,value3,value4,value5 but this is not fixed it may very which are repeating value. I want to display that value with relative count like my output and it should also show field2 value and count with resultant output.

**Here is my query**

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
     {
       "_id": {field1:"$field1",field2:"$field2"}
    }
  },
  { 
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }
]);
```

Here is my data

```
    { 
    "_id" : "1",
    "field1" : "value1", 
    "field2" : "abc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "2",
    "field1" : "value2", 
    "field2" : "xyz"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "3",
    "field1" : "value2", 
    "field2" : "abc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "4",
    "field1" : "value3", 
    "field2" : "abc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "5",
    "field1" : "value1", 
    "field2" : "xyz"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6",
    "field1" : "value3", 
    "field2" : "xyz"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "7",
    "field1" : "value1", 
    "field2" : "abc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "8",
    "field1" : "value2", 
    "field2" : "xyz"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "9",
    "field1" : "value1", 
    "field2" : "abc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "10",
    "field1" : "value1", 
    "field2" : "abc"
}
{ 
    "_id" : "11",
    "field1" : "value2", 
    "field2" : "xyz"
}
```

**and my Output suppose to like this:**

```
{ 
 "field1.value1" : 0
}
{ 
"field1.value2" : 1
}
{ 
"field1.value3" : 12
}
{
 "field2.abc" : 50
}
{
 "field2.xyz" : 5
}
```

Let me know how it's possible.

Comment: Can you please add some dummy data of your collection for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The $group stage allows you to have an _id on multiple fields. This creates a grouping for all existing combinations of your different fields.

First of all, the count field and the accumulator 'sum' should be within the group stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
     {
       "_id": { field1:"$field1", field2:"$field2" },
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
]);
```

You can then sum up the results on the client side over a reduced number of entries. This will take negligible amount of time since number of unique values of 'field1' and 'field2' would be very less when compared to the original set of documents.

The other option that I can think of is to use multiple aggregation queries, but that is solely up to you depending on performance.

Comment: I don't want to mixup two fields count in one result. It' would be better if we can separate it as per my result output shown.

Comment: That is preferable, but I don't think it is possible using a single aggregation query. As we pass through an aggregation stage, it transforms the data and hence, it is not possible to get back the original data to do a seperate count. You can maybe try MapReduce but that will be much slower compared to this.

Comment: can you please write a query for that, I do not have any idea of Map-reduce?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `$objectToArray`operator in 3.4.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT"}}}
  ,{$unwind: "$x"}
  ,{$match: {"x.k": {$ne: "_id"}}}
  ,{$group: {_id: {f:"$x.k", v: "$x.v"}, n: {$sum:1}}}
  ,{$project: {fv: {$concat: [ "$_id.f", ".", "$_id.v" ]}, n:1, _id:0 }}
                    ]);
```

This dynamically works on any number of fields.  If you want to restrict what it's doing, then add a `{$match: {"$x.k": {$ne: "fieldname you don't want"}}}`
This is the output given the input posted above:

```
{ "n" : 5, "fv" : "field2.xyz" }
{ "n" : 4, "fv" : "field1.value2" }
{ "n" : 2, "fv" : "field1.value3" }
{ "n" : 6, "fv" : "field2.abc" }
{ "n" : 5, "fv" : "field1.value1" }
```

Here is a solution that meets the exact spec by using `$arrayToObject` "resynthesize" a doc with the desired field names:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$project: {x: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT"}}}
  ,{$unwind: "$x"}
  ,{$match: {"x.k": {$ne: "_id"}}}
  ,{$group: {_id: {f:"$x.k", v: "$x.v"}, n: {$sum:1}}}
  ,{$project: { _id:0, xx: [ [ {$concat: ["$_id.f", ".", "$_id.v"]}, "$n"] ] }}
  ,{$replaceRoot: { newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$xx"}}}
                    ]);
```

Yielding:

```
{ "field2.xyz" : 5 }
{ "field1.value2" : 4 }
{ "field1.value3" : 2 }
{ "field2.abc" : 6 }
{ "field1.value1" : 5 }
```